# Catch changes from Singelton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a Singelton class that communicates with a simple chat server. It receives messages and puts the messages in an `NSMutableArray`

Currently i am updating my tableView in my firstViewController by reading the data inside my `NSMutableArray` - this works just fine.

The only problem is that in order to update the table i have to switch to another view and then back again (even though my `NSMutableArray` is being updating live with new data within my Singelton class).

How can i make my table update as soon as my `NSMutableArray`has new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your singleton can [post a notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Posting.html) when data changes. [Register](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html) your view controller as observer for this notification, and update your views when you receive it.

Comment: How do i send the notification from my Singelton and receive it in the viewController that contains my table?

Comment: This did the trick: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/basics-of-notifications.html